# OneSignal - Get Error after receiving push Notif

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

Based on [this guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup), I try to integrate my existing Android apps with `OneSignal`. I put `OneSignal` code in **MainActivity.java** :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle pSavedInstanceState) 
{

OneSignal.startInit(this)
.setNotificationOpenedHandler(new OneSignalNotificationOpenedHandler())
.setNotificationReceivedHandler(new OneSignalReceivedHandler())
.init();        

}
```

Of course, i have created the class handler for `.setNotificationOpenedHandler` and `.setNotificationReceivedHandler`
The class handler area (in **MainActivity.java**) :

```
private class OneSignalReceivedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler
{
    @Override
    public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {
        JSONObject data = notification.payload.additionalData;
        String customKey;

        Log.d("onesignal=","onesignal receiver");
        if (data != null) {
            customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
            if (customKey != null)
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
        }
    }
}

private class OneSignalNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler
{

    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
        OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
        JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
        String customKey;

        Log.d("onesignal=","onesignal open handler");

        if (data != null) {
            customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
            if (customKey != null)
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
        }

        if (actionType == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.ActionTaken)
            Log.i("OneSignalExample", "Button pressed with id: " + result.action.actionID);
    }
}
```

But after getting push Notification, my apps close suddenly and showing error : `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method`

The Error i got after receiving Push Notification :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-13-thread-1 Process: com.myapps, PID: 24189
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage$Notification.getBody()' on
>   a null object reference at
>   com.mylib.FCMMessageReceiverService.onMessageReceived(FCMMessageReceiverService.java:26)
>   at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzo(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzn(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzm(Unknown
>   Source) at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

any Idea ?

Many Thanks before...

===Update

My **MyFirebaseMessagingService.java** class :

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notifictionBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notifictionBuilder.setContentTitle("My Application");

        notifictionBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        notifictionBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notifictionBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        notifictionBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notifictionBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check  my solution ??

Comment: Hi, Yes Thanks. but too night here. if i have more question, i will reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggest ,

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String
>   com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage$Notification.getBody()' on
>   a null object reference at

Check the file named

> MyFirebaseMessagingService

within it you will have this function

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService  extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
```

Add a **notification object** on your $message. The body of your POST request must be something like:

```
{
    "to" : "aUniqueKey",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "Blah Blah!",
      "title" : "Hey vs. Hello"
    },
    "data" : {
      "Nick" : "Amigos",
      "Room" : "Lasta vs Avista"
    }
}
```

Your `remoteMessage.getNotification()` returns`null` because the body of your POST request doesn't contain a notification object.

Comment: Hi, i stil dont understand how to add notification object to $message. i have update my question. thanks...

Comment: Update your payload from server side that you are sending from server  for notification that payload must have body object as I suggested

Comment: You don't need MyFirebaseMessagingService here  use OneSignalReceivedHandler to handle any onesignal notification received .DOn't even use MyFirebaseMessagingService in case you just want to handle one signal notification .Its library is handling everything you will receive notification in notificationReceived of OneSignalReceivedHandler class .

Comment: Cheeck this demo how oneSignal works in Android https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/master/Examples/AndroidStudio/app/src/main/java/com/onesignal/example/ExampleApplication.java

Comment: Hi, i have used `android multidexapplication` instead `ExampleApplication ` has in above link. so any idea ? thanks

Comment: btw, why i use `MyFirebaseMessagingService.java`, before try to integrate with OneSignal i've done before with FireBase Push Notif although the result was not good. it's why in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file i have service that call `FCMMessageReceiverService`

Comment: remove that class if you are using OneSignal and not FCM that class will only be helpful when you are using FCM  so remove that class from app and  manifest too. Problem in  In class FCMMessageReceiverService   onMessageReceived function alos getting called  but you only need  class OneSignalReceivedHandler . function named notificationReceived . Both class trying to receive that message so just remove  FCMMessageReceiverService and from manifest too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137403/discussion-between-ravindra-shekhawat-and-user2226388).